# Ubuntu 15.04 can not find Drive

Tags: dual-boot, mount, hard-drive

whenever i try to access my drive this appears and i can't access my drive. I am using 15.04 alongside windows 8.1

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/sharif/EEE: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda2" "/media/sharif/EEE"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [disable Fast Boot in Windows 8.1](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-or-enable-fast-startup-in-windows-8-1/).

[How Fast Boot works?](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-windows-8-hybrid-shutdown-fast-boot-feature-works/) -

> Windows 8 doesn't totally shut down when you click the Shut down
>   command. Instead it only partially shuts down and partially
>   hibernates. This is the Hybrid Shutdown part of the equation. Then,
>   when you turn on your computer, Windows 8 starts very quickly because
>   it only has to partially boot up and partially wake up. This is the
>   Fast Boot part of the equation.